# Swift Firestore, allow users to block other users and therefore that content won't be displayed

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have submitted my App to the Apple Appstore however its getting rejected on "A mechanism for users to block abusive users". I am not sure how I would go about implementing this to the app. I tried using Firestore rules but that did not work. Has anyone any ideas on how to do this? The app itself is a social recipes app so there is feeds of recipes posted by different users so if a person blocks that user they should no longer see their posts not he feeds.

Comment: You could just add a document in Firestore with a list of users that the user has blocked, and then you can verify that the post isn't from a blocked user before displaying it. Also, is the abusive user not supposed to see the other user's post, or is it the other way around. It's not clear from your question.

Comment: You just asked this same question two days ago. Please stay focused on one question and update it as more information becomes available.

Comment: I am sorry you feel that way, SO is an amazing resource full of people trying to help. From this question, you are looking for a way to *block abusive users* (because of their posts) and your other question states *They want a way to report users* (to block them because of their posts) which is the same thing. From this question *I tried using Firestore rules* and from your other question *So I tried to use Firestore rules*. The concept of the two questions is similar. I would suggest being open to working on *that* question. There are a couple of suggestions already - did you try anything?

Comment: I sorted it out and they weren't similar solutions, and I think you were misreading my two questions one was blocking a user, when user is blocked none of there posts will show up and the second question was reporting a single post, I used a counter for the reporting a post and when it hits 10 reports it removes it for everyone and then for blocking a user I added a new array field to user documents where they can add the ids of the users they wish to block. Two completely different solutions